# Differentiability implies continuity in a norm vector space framework proof.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I am following *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh.

Here is the definition of derivative in the relevant setting and the proof that I have yet to fully understand

[image]
[image]

I am not sure how this implies continuity, is an alternative definition of continuity being used?

Comment: where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the usual definition of continuity in your setting

> **Definition**. *Let $U$ be an open subset of $\def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n$, $p \in U$ and $f \colon U \to \R^m$. $f$ is called continuous at $p$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $\delta > 0$ such that for all $q \in U$ such that $|p - q| < \delta$ we have that $|f(p) - f(q)| < \epsilon$.*

Now we reformulate the definition to match the argument above:

> **Lemma**. Let $f \colon U \to \R^m$ and $p \in U$ as above. Then $f$ is continuous at $p$ iff 
>   $$ |f(p+v) - f(p)| \to 0, \qquad \textit{ as } v \to 0 $$

*Proof*. Its just writing $q$ as $p+v$ in the definition given above. If you want to be more concrete, then argue as follows: 
Suppose $f$ is continuous at $p$, for $\epsilon > 0$ given, choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(p) - f(q)| < \epsilon$ for $|p-q| < \delta$. But now for all $v$ with $|v| < \delta$, we have that $|f(p+v) - f(p)| < \epsilon$ (as with $q := p+v$ we have $|p-q| = |v| < \epsilon$). This proves $|f(p+v)-f(p)| \to 0$ for $v \to 0$.
On the other hand, suppose the condition in the lemma holds. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta > 0$ such that for $|v| < \delta$ we have $|f(p+v) - f(p)| < \epsilon$. Given $q$ with $| p-q | < \delta$, we have $|f(p) - f(q)| < \delta$. $\square$